# String variable is truncated when inserted into an nvarchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I take XML from a webservice and it's very long (> 1 million characters). I put the XML in an SSIS variable.

I want to put the *raw* XML from the variable into a SQL Server 2012 table. Table column is `nvarchar(max)`.

From sql task i use simple

```
Insert (xml) values (@variable)
```

However when i look at the column length in SQL Server, only 500k chars there!

Why is this?

Comment: What is the data type of the @Variable? If it is of DT_WSTR then SQL Server equivalent bytes is 4000.

Comment: i am aware of this xml data type, but problem here is to insert from ssis utf-16 string variable to nvarchar column.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are checking the length of the value in your package and in SQL Server? For example, have you used the .NET `String.Length` property in your package, and in SQL Server have you used `LEN` or `DATALENGTH`? Note that `DATALENGTH` returns double what `LEN` returns for `nvarchar` values: `select len(N'abc'), datalength(N'abc')`

Comment: using the len(xml) here.. it's very clear to see also from select column value that the xml ends before the closing tag.